# Parts of ajax function can just be reached by debugging

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, debugging, firebug

I have an asp.net application in which I user jquery.
In my jquery code I have a simple ajax request like this:

```
var allowDelete = true;
$.ajax({
              url: '...',
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'post',
              data: { something...}
          })
          .success(function (response) {
              if (response.Passed) {
                 //do something
              }
              else {
                  //do something
                  allowDelete = false;
              }
          })
          .error(function () {
              // do something
          });

 if (allowDelete) {
//something
}
```

as you can see I want a var set false when my Passed var has the value false.
When I just run the code without any breakpoints the allowDelete var is never set false. And when I put a breakpoint(in firebug) next to the row where I set the allowDelete false it never hits the breakpoint. But when I put a breakpoint at the beginnig of the function and debug through the whole ajax it everything works perfectly fine and get the result I wanted. Any idea where the mistake could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you asked this question more than 1 month ago, it might be late, but hope that helps:

The reason is that AJAX is asynchronous:
1. You set allowDelete to true.
2. You call your AJAX function. It starts working, turns to your server, etc.
3. You check allowDelete. It is still true.
4. AJAX call returns, sets allowDelete to false if the conditions were OK (response is not Passed).

So because of asynchrony, allowDelete is being checked right after you call your AJAX function, doesn't wait for the answer(the AJAX callback method). Basically, your AJAX functions callback method runs too late.

When you use breakpoint, your AJAX call has enough time to get its answer from the server so the fourth point from above happens earlier than the third.

Comment: thanks for your anwser. I actually solved this issue by  setting allowDelete false at the beginnging and true then the response Passed. But from your anwser which I find quit comprehensible this seems like a very bad solution. Do you have an idea how to do that more elegant?

Comment: If there aren't too many code rows in your "if (allowDelete){}" condition, you could place it into the else branch of your callback method, when you set the allowDelete to false.
If you need that code part to use it in several places in your code, or there are several rows in your condition, you could place it into a different function and call it from the callback method (in this case you don't even need the allowDelete variable).
I hope that was clear, my English knowledge isn't the best. : - )